# How to save variables that were changed in custom inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

EDIT: THE PROBLEM WAS THIS LINE:  = new List(10). Commenting it and adding the SerializeField attribute seems to do the job

In Unity3D I am trying to build a simple menu builder script that would help me create menus for my game.

I have created a class that holds the sub menu items in a list and created a custom inspector for the class so i can easily remove items from the list.

My problem is when I close the scene, the list isn't saved. I haven't created custom inspectors before so I am not sure that I am doing it the right way.

This is my code: (EDIT: tried adding [SerializeField, HideInInspector] to the list and it saved the list but the references got lost...)

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MenuSettings menuSettings; // Only holds reference to the MenuController prefab
    [SerializeField] private string text;
    [SerializeField] private BackgroundController subMenuItemsHolder;
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector] private List<MenuController> subMenuItems/* = new List<MenuController>(10)*/;

    public byte SubMenusCount => (byte)subMenuItems.Count;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                text = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public MenuController GetSubMenuAtIndex(byte index)
    {
        if (!IsIndexValid(index))
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
        }
        return subMenuItems[index];
    }
    public void AddSubMenu(string text)
    {
        MenuController subMenu = menuSettings.CreateInstance(subMenuItemsHolder.transform); // Just calling Instantiate
        subMenu.Text = text;
        subMenu.name = text;
        subMenuItems.Add(subMenu);
    }
    public void RemoveSubMenuAtIndex(byte index, bool destroy = true)
    {
        if (!IsIndexValid(index))
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
        }
        if (destroy)
        {
            if (Application.isPlaying)
            {
                Destroy(subMenuItems[index].gameObject);
            }
        else
        {
            UnityEditor.Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(subMenuItems[index].gameObject);
        }
    }
    subMenuItems.RemoveAt(index);
}

private bool IsIndexValid(byte index)
{
    return index >= 0 && index < subMenuItems.Count;
}
```

}

And the code for custom inspector:

```c#
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MenuController))]
public class MenuControllerEditor : Editor
{
    private MenuController menuController;
    private string newSubMenuText = string.Empty;
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        byte count = menuController.SubMenusCount;
        MenuController subMenuItem;
        GUILayout.Label($"Sub menu items count: {count}");
        for (byte i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            subMenuItem = menuController.GetSubMenuAtIndex(i);
            Undo.RecordObject(subMenuItem, "Changed sub menu item's text");
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            subMenuItem.Text = GUILayout.TextField(subMenuItem.Text, GUILayout.MinWidth(200), GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
            if (GUILayout.Button("X", GUILayout.Width(50)))
            {
                menuController.RemoveSubMenuAtIndex(i);
                menuController.RefreshLayout();
                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                return;
            }
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
        subMenuItem = null;
        GUILayout.Space(10);
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        Undo.RecordObject(menuController, "Changed new sub menu text");
        newSubMenuText = GUILayout.TextField(newSubMenuText, GUILayout.MinWidth(200), GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
        if (GUILayout.Button("Add", GUILayout.Width(50)))
        {
            menuController.AddSubMenu(newSubMenuText.Trim());
            menuController.RefreshLayout();
            newSubMenuText = string.Empty;
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        menuController = (MenuController)target;
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        menuController = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the List serialized as the other fields so it is stored together with the scene/prefab asset. Anyway note that your code currently will fail to build since you are using parts of the `UnityEditor` namespace in your class ... you should wrap these with `#if UNITY_EDITOR` and `#endif` in roder to exclude them from builds ... e.g. `UnityEditor.Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(subMenuItems[index].gameObject);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried adding [SerializeField, HideInInspector] to the list variable and it did save it but I get null reference exception. it seems that when the scene closes the reference get deleted

Comment: what does `menuSettings.CreateInstance`?

Comment: @derHugo nothing special, only a call to the Instantiate method for the prefab (or PrefabUtility.Instantiate if we are in editor)

Comment: Maybe `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()` will help you ? Try to add this line at the very end of the method ÒnInspectorGUI`. You could add `serializedObject.Update()` as the very first line as well.

Comment: @Malphegal Tried it just now but almost same result. When I close the scene the list is saved but the references get lost. The only difference I see is that now the first element is saved some how.